# How do you initialize a variable in a constructor body and not in the defintion?

Tags: c++, c++11

Win7-64 bits
cygwin
g++ -std=gnu++11 (4.8.3)

In the fragment below the variable 'partition' must be initialized after the call to slipInit. The compiler complains (oh so bitterly) unless I initialize partition in the definition (after the ':'). I've just started using gnu++11 and so this is an unfortunate surprise. Are there any easy workarounds or must I create another method to do the initialization?

```
StringPartition::StringPartition(vector<string*>* vec, long debugFlags) 
                                : vec(*vec)
                            , debugFlags(debugFlags) {
      SlipCellBase::slipInit(SLIPALLOCATION, SLIPALLOCATION);
      partition = * new SlipHeader();
}; // StringPartition::StringPartition()

Error Message
error: uninitialized reference member 'StringPartition::partition' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Seems as though `partition` would probably better as a smart pointer than a reference.

Comment: What is and how do I construct a 'smart pointer' (I'm only a dumb programmer)?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/10077 C++11 provides several smart pointer types. The most popular are [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: *Why* is `partition` a reference? Those are meant to refer to things that already exist, not newly created things.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to initialize a [reference data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) (since C++11 you can either do that in the constructor's initializer list or with a brace-or-equal initializer) but it requires a function call first, you should prefer a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) over a reference (*pseudocode ahead*):

```
class StringPartition {
  public:

  StringPartition() {
      SlipCellBase::slipInit(SLIPALLOCATION, SLIPALLOCATION);
      partition.reset(new SlipHeader());
  }

  std::unique_ptr<SlipHeader> partition;
};
```

In C++14 [you could even do better](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
partition = std::make_unique<SlipHeader>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* "initialise" members in the constructor body. You may only assign to them. All members are assuredly initialised — with their default constructors, and only if it's possible (else compilation failure) — before execution of the constructor body commences. Since `partition` is a reference, it *must* be initialised and cannot be default-initialised.

Your problem has arisen because `SlipCellBase` does not take advantage of RAII and therefore does not fit into the 21st century model of resource management within classes. Your best option is probably to make `partition` a `std::unique_ptr<SlipHeader>` so that it can take on an "unset" value until you're ready to assign to it. The smart nature of `std::unique_ptr<>` will clean it up for you when your `StringPartition` goes out of scope. Still, be under no illusion: this is still, ultimately, a hack around poor design.